# Best way to find value in List when list is sorted

Tags: java, algorithm, search, sorting

Let's say I have a Java ArrayList, that is sorted. Now I would like to find the index of value x. What would be the fastest (without more than 30 lines of code) way to do this? Use of the IndexOf() method? Iterate through all values in a simple for loop? Use of some cool algorithm? We are talking about around let's say 50 integer keys.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search), but since it's only 50 items, who cares (unless you have to do it millions of times)?  A simple linear search is simpler and the difference in performance for 50 items is negligible.

**Edit**: You could also use the built-in java.util.Collections [binarySearch](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) method.  Be aware, that it will return an insertion point even if the item isn't found.  You may need to make an extra couple of checks to make sure that the item really is the one you want.  Thanks to @Matthew for the pointer.

Comment: For fifty keys, I completely agree. Developer time is more important than CPU time these days. Use IndexOf() and be on your way.

Comment: Except that Java /has/ this functionality.

Comment: Binary search is the way to go. The list may currently only have 50 items, but who knows what the code will have to handle in a year or two..

Comment: @Matthew -- didn't know that -- been a while since I've written much Java, though I just started writing a small applet yesterday for a project that I'm working on.  Will update.

Comment: If the item is not found it returns (-(insertion point) - 1).  So if you don't care about insertion points, just check if the return value is non-negative.

Answer (score 6):

tvanfosson is right, that the time for either will be very low, so unless this code runs very frequently it won't make much difference.

However, Java has built-in functionality for binary searches of Lists (including ArrayLists), [Collections.binarySearch](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T)).

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
// ...fill with values

Collections.sort( myList );
int index = Collections.binarySearch( myList, "searchVal" );
```

Edit: untested code

Answer (score 1):

If the keys have a acceptable distribution, [Interpolation Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) might be very fast way considering execution time.

Considering coding time `IndexOf()` is the way to go (or a built-in in binary search if availiable for your data type (I am from C# and don't know Java)).