# Find the Value in List

Tags: java, collections, return, return-value

How to find Specific Value in List..
Ex:
This is in Demo1 Class method

```
   /*some code*/ ---------
    ---------//Generating List<Date> d1 and d2 hear  
    public List<Date> returnList(List<Date> d1,List<Date> d2)
    {
          List<Date> startDate=new ArrayList<Date>();

          startDate.add(d1);
          startDate.add(d2);
         return startDate;
    }
```

And Demo2 Class i'm Using this method in service class that method i want same  `d1,d2` lists.

Comment: Look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901546/best-way-to-find-value-in-list-when-list-is-sorted

Comment: I am unable to parse the question.

Comment: @PradeepSimha: Who says the list is sorted?

Comment: parse the list using an integer and then use: list.get(integer); That will do the trick  .

Comment: The above doesn't compile. Is that the problem? Do you want us to explain what the error message you get from the compiler means? Have you read it?

Comment: @Thilo, I gave a general link which speaks on same-line, of course its need to be applied to his context.

Comment: This follows from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878263/is-it-possible-to-return-two-arraylist-values-in-one-method-in-java

Comment: What would make this simpler is if you had an interval of dates and you were trying to find which interval a date was within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont like it, but to get it compiled you will need something like

```
 public List<List<Date>> returnList(List<Date> d1,List<Date> d2)
{
      List<List<Date>> startDate=new ArrayList<List<Date>>();

      startDate.add(d1);
      startDate.add(d2);
     return startDate;
}
```

Your return type should be a List of List

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [List#indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
int x = listOfDates.indexOf(theDate);
```

Returns the (first) index of the element, or -1 if it is not in the list.

Depends on `equals()` to work properly, which may or may not be tricky with Dates (you will have to set the exact same time).